# How to insert a HTML Code in Multicell FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I wrote a PDF with PHP and FPDF.

I would like to insert in a Multicell in HTML code.

Example:

```
 <strong>pippo</strong>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: i have see this link but it not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider use [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org) who provide a [WriteHTML](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a8458280d15b73d3baffb28eebe2d9246) function and stay mainly compatible with FPDF